# Angular directive require on the same element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi trying to require on the same element. According to angular docs this is possible.

> A ^ prefix would make the directive look for the controller on its own
>   element or its parents; without any prefix, the directive would look
>   on its own element only.

Following the explanation. I have two directives, myD and myC... want to be able to access myD from myC's link ctrl attribute.

I've included a link to my codepen example.

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);


app.directive("myD", function() {
   return {
      restrict : "E",
      template : "<b>myd</d>"
   }
});

app.directive("myC", function() {
   return {
      require : "myD",
      restrict : "A",
      link : function (scope, attr, ele, ctrl) {
         alert(JSON.stringify(ctrl));
      }
   }

});

<div ng-app="app">
   <my-d my-c></my-d>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/mantisimo/pen/KWOxeg

Getting the following error:

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'myD', required by directive 'myC',
>   can't be found!

Comment: put  controller: function(){} inside directive `myD`?

Comment: Thanks for that....literally just figured it! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `require`, you ask angular to inject the controller of the required element. In your case, the controller was undefined.

The error was in `myD` where you need to declare a controller.

```
app.directive("myD", function() {
   return {
      restrict : "E",
      template : "<b>myd</d>",
      controller: function(){}
   }
});
```

Comment: Just figured it two seconds ago...It's funny how when you define the problem you see the problem... Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Hopefully will save someone else some pain :)

Comment: @Mantisimo next time, use a plastic duck ;-)

Comment: @Mantisimo if you use components instead of controllers, there is a default controller declared in each https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#comparison-between-directive-definition-and-component-definition

Comment: And it's recomended to use components if you don't use the link nor the compile functions